# Custom serialization of null/initial values in ABAP using `CALL TRANSFORMATION`

Tags: json, transformation, abap

You can serialize ABAP structures to JSON using the `CALL TRANSFORMATION` command. Is there any possibility to serialize `null` values for initial fields or ignore initial fields?

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF t_my_type,
         foo TYPE string,
         bar TYPE string,
       END OF t_my_type.

DATA ls_structure TYPE t_my_type.
ls_structure-foo = 'some value'.
ASSERT ls_structure-bar IS INITIAL.
DATA(lo_json_writer) = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE result = ls_structure RESULT XML lo_json_writer.
DATA(lv_json_xstring) = lo_json_writer->get_output( ).
WRITE cl_abap_codepage=>convert_from( source = lv_json_xstring ).
```

The result of this minimal working example is:

```
{
  "RESULT": {
    "FOO": "some value",
    "BAR": ""
  }
}
```

In other languages (that need to process the json exported from SAP) an empty string `""` and `null` are not the same and do require additional processing/handling I'd like to avoid. I want a result like this

```
{
  "RESULT": {
    "FOO": "some value",
    "BAR": null
  }
}
```

or ignore the initial value like this:

```
{
  "RESULT": {
    "FOO": "some value"
  }
}
```

Can I pass some additional rules to `CALL TRANSFORMATION` on how to handle `null`/initial values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pure ABAP language does not have a concept of null values, except the [null references](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abennull_reference_glosry.htm). The most approaching "concept" is the [initial value](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abeninitial_value_glosry.htm).

An `ID` transformation used to produce JSON format can never produce the JSON value "null" from an initial value. The serialization of a null reference produces `{}`, and other types produce either `""` (types C, STRING, X, XSTRING, the last two ones being expressed in base64), `"000..."` (type N), `"0000-00-00"` (type D), `"00:00:00"` (type T) or `0` (types I, P, F, DECFLOAT16, DECFLOAT34, INT1, INT2, INT8).

To serialize only non-initial values, you may use the [option](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_transformation_options.htm) `initial_components = 'suppress'` of `CALL TRANSFORMATION`:

```
CALL TRANSFORMATION ID 
  SOURCE result = ls_structure 
  RESULT XML lo_json_writer
  OPTIONS initial_components = 'suppress'.
```

The following program demonstrates the differences of JSON values, when they are initial and not initial, and when the option `initial_components = 'suppress'` is used. Note: so that the data reference is serialized, I had to use the option "data_refs = 'heap-or-create'`.

- initial values: `{"RESULT":{"STRING":"","CHAR4":"","INT":0,"BINFLOAT":0,"DECFLOAT":0,"NUMC4":"0000","DATE":"0000-00-00","TIME":"00:00:00","XSTRING":"","HEX2":"","DREF":{},"OREF":{}}}`
- initial values + option `initial_components = 'suppress'`: `{"RESULT":{}}`
- non-initial values: `{"RESULT":{"STRING":"a ","CHAR4":"b","INT":-1,"BINFLOAT":-2.9999999999999999E-1,"DECFLOAT":-0.3,"NUMC4":"0001","DATE":"2019-11-01","TIME":"10:49:00","XSTRING":"/w==","HEX2":"/w==","DREF":{"%ref":"#d1"},"OREF":{"%ref":"#o10"}},"%heap":{"o10":{"%type":"http://www.sap.com/abapxml/classes/program/ZDEMO_JSON_INITIAL:LCL_CLASS","%val":{"local.LCL_CLASS":{"ATTRIBUTE":"d"}}},"d1":{"%type":"abap:characters","%maxLength":1,"%val":"c"}}}`

Program:

```
REPORT zdemo_json_initial.
TYPES: BEGIN OF t_my_type,
        string   TYPE string,
        char4    TYPE c LENGTH 4,
        int      TYPE i,
        binfloat TYPE f,
        decfloat TYPE decfloat16,
        numc4    TYPE n LENGTH 4,
        date     TYPE d,
        time     TYPE t,
        xstring  TYPE xstring,
        hex2     TYPE x LENGTH 2,
        dref     TYPE REF TO data,
        oref     TYPE REF TO object,
      END OF t_my_type.
CLASS lcl_class DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_serializable_object.
    DATA attribute TYPE string.
ENDCLASS.

DATA(initial) = value t_my_type( ).
DATA(oref) = NEW lcl_class( ).
oref->attribute = 'd'.
DATA(non_initial) = VALUE t_my_type( string = `a ` char4 = `b ` int = -1 binfloat = '-0.3'
    decfloat = '-0.3' numc4 = '1' date = '20191101' time = '104900'
    xstring = 'FF' hex2 = 'FF' dref = REF #( 'c' ) oref = oref ).

DATA(lo_json_writer1) = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE result = initial RESULT XML lo_json_writer1
    OPTIONS data_refs = 'heap-or-create'.
DATA(json_initial) = lo_json_writer1->get_output( ).

DATA(lo_json_writer2) = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE result = initial RESULT XML lo_json_writer2
    OPTIONS data_refs = 'heap-or-create' INITIAL_COMPONENTS = 'suppress'.
DATA(json_initial_suppress) = lo_json_writer2->get_output( ).

DATA(lo_json_writer3) = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).
CALL TRANSFORMATION id SOURCE result = non_initial RESULT XML lo_json_writer3
    OPTIONS data_refs = 'heap-or-create'.
DATA(json_non_initial) = lo_json_writer3->get_output( ).
```

Comment: Side note: I just checked the serialization of an uninitialized data reference and got an empty object `{}`, not a real `null`.

Comment: @konstantin I thoroughly edited my answer as I realized it could be misinterpreted and I added a program to show how initial values and non-initial values are serialized to JSON (my answer being restricted to the `ID` transformation).

Comment: If only SAP delivered such detailed documentation and working exxamples as your answers... ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using updated system, you can use **/ui2/cl_json** class. Otherwise, you can use [json.abap](https://github.com/oliverit/json.abap) library.